# JFReeCharts XYPlot is it possible to change shapes inside legends

Tags: jfreechart

```
lt.setPosition(RectangleEdge.BOTTOM);
lt.setItemFont(old);
// get the range axis and add the $ symbol for the values
NumberAxis na = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();       
// set font
na.setLabelFont(fAxisFont); 
na.setTickLabelFont(fAxisFont);
na.setAutoRange(true);
```

The above is my code snippet.Can anyone tell how to to chang shapes inside legends

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222557/jfreechart-legend-display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LegendItem` infers its `Shape` from the corresponding series, which can be changed as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669529/230513). This [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513) example shows one way to render a `LegendItem` in an external component.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following workaround:

```
StandardXYItemRenderer renderer = new StandardXYItemRenderer() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    @Override
    public LegendItem getLegendItem(int datasetIndex, int series) {
        LegendItem legend = super.getLegendItem(datasetIndex,
                series);
        return new LegendItem(legend.getLabel(),
                legend.getDescription(), legend.getToolTipText(),
                legend.getURLText(), Plot.DEFAULT_LEGEND_ITEM_BOX,
                legend.getFillPaint());
    }
};

...

plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

Result:
[image]